# Why can't I read my data from the array?

Tags: c, arrays

I am reading data from a file and writing it into an array. This works but I can't seem to read it back out of the array properly. Where is the mistake?

```
int main(){

    struct mountain{
        char name[300];
        char height[5];
    };

    struct mountain mountainArray[8];

    fp = fopen("berge.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return(-1);
    }

    int i=0;
    while ( fgets(readLine, buflen, fp)){
        if(i<8){

            char * p;

            p = strtok (readLine,":");
            if (p != NULL){

                strcpy(mountainArray[i].name,p);
                p = strtok (NULL, ":");
                if (p != NULL)
                    strcpy(mountainArray[i].height,p);
            }

            i++;

        }
    }

    unsigned int f;
    for (f=0; f<8; f++){

        printf("%s\n", mountainArray[i].name);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in line

```
printf("%c\n", mountainArray[i].name);
```

I think you mean `f` for the index, not `i`.

(and Ivaylo is right - you want `%s` for strings.)

Comment: That did it how embarassing!

Comment: Please handle error conditions as well in the program @HansEn by using setting NULL value for structure members, else in for loop it would print out junk for rest of members.

Answer (score 0):

You should print a string using `%s` format specifier not `%c`.

Comment: Yeah. That prints me p@ every line. If I debug, I can see that the array is filled with data. I just can´t seem to read it back out.